# Code from mathematica to matlab -- table command

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I have the following code from mathematica and trying to do it with matlab but I can't do it:

```
tX := Sum[Random[] - 0.5, {m}]/m
m=1;
km=10m;
dataX = Table[tX, {km}]
fig2 = ListPlot[dataX, PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], PointSize[0.015]}]
```

I did this :

```
tx=sum(rand(1,m)-0.5) ./ m;
m=100;
km=100*m;
datax=zeros(tx,1);
for i=1:km
    datax(i,1)=[tx];
end
```

I have two problems:

1. In mathematica the tx **:=** means that the variable tx is evaluated each time it is used.
   How can I accomplish this in matlab?
2. I have some mistake or mistakes in my code because when it gives me the plot it gives me a straight line but it should give a big number of points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
m = 1;
km = 10*m;
tX = @(m) sum( rand(m,1) - 0.5 )/ m;
dataX = arrayfun(tX, m * ones(km,1)); 
plot(1:km, dataX, 'r.')
```

To generate an instance of `tX`, just type `tX(m)`, where `m` is the value you want.

to explain some of this:

`tX` is a function handle,  it is equivalent to `tX[m_] := Sum[RandomReal[],{m}]/m` in Mathematica.

dataX is constructed with `arrayfun` which applies the function handle in the first slot to each element in the vector in the second slot.  That command is roughly equivalent to `Table[tX[m],{km}]` in Mathematica.

Comment: Exactly. By the way, you can replace `sum(rand(m,1)-0.5)/m` by `mean(rand(m,1))-0.5`

Comment: Good point, and to change to point size change the plot command to `plot(1:km,dataX, 'r.','MarkerSize',WHAT_YOU_WANT)`